# Как остановить выполнение задания, работая с библиотекой schedule в Python?

Tags: python

Для добавления определенного функционала телеграм боту, пытаюсь написать скрипт, который будет по команде от пользователя вносить изменения в БД sqlite до достижения определенных условий или до новой команды от пользователя. Для этого пытаюсь использовать библиотеку `schedule` (или асинхронную `aioschedule`), но никак не могу прервать цикл выполнения запущенного задания.

```
import schedule
import time
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db/gecko.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def some_task():
    cursor.execute('UPDATE table SET column = column + 1 WHERE id = ?', ('123',))
    conn.commit()

def start():
    job = schedule.every(2).seconds.do(some_task)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        cursor.execute('SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = ?', ('123',))
        recs = cursor.fetchall()
        print(schedule.get_jobs())
        for row in recs:
            if row[0] == 70:
                schedule.cancel_job(job)
                break
        time.sleep(1)

if input('Start?') == 'y':
    start()
```

В итоге обновление данных прекращается, но цикл не прерывается, судя по тому, что в консоль продолжается вывод строки `print(schedule.get_jobs())`

И стоит ли вообще управлять изменением в БД из основного кода, учитывая, что пользователей, в теории, может быть 100+, и у для каждого будет запускаться свой цикл? Или лучше написать внешний скрипт, который будет парсить данные с БД и начинать цикл при считывании определенного триггера в БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def start():
    ...
    while True: # <-- 1-й цикл
        ...
        for row in recs: # <-- 2-й цикл
            if row[0] == 70:
                schedule.cancel_job(job)
                break # <-- прерываем внутренний цикл
```

`break` прерывает только один, самый внутренний цикл, а у вас два вложенных цикла, внешний цикл продолжает работать. Чтобы выйти из обоих циклов сразу вам тут можно использовать `return`:

```py
            if row[0] == 70:
                schedule.cancel_job(job)
                return # <-- прерываем работу всей функции
```

Если бы циклы не были внутри функции, пришлось бы делать более сложно, например, заводить переменную, которую потом сбрасывать:

```py
    do_job = True
    while do_job: # <-- 1-й цикл
        ...
        for row in recs: # <-- 2-й цикл
            if row[0] == 70:
                schedule.cancel_job(job)
                do_job = False # <-- чтобы прервать внешний цикл
                break # <-- прерываем внутренний цикл
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Весь день над этим вопросом голову ломал..